# What is the Unix "logger command" equivalent in PowerShell?

Tags: unix, powershell

I'm converting unix kornshell files to powershell files.
While converting, I came across this line
 "logger -p local0.error -t ID-ERROR AM BOD failed to start".

Can any body give me the Powershell equivalent for the above code?

Thanks

Comment: The `logger` command sends a message to the `syslogd`, which writes it to a log file. Is there a specific log file you need to write to? Is there some other process watching for the errors?

Comment: Answer me in both ways,Using specific log file and and without using specific log file.

Comment: The direct psh equivalent of `logger` is `Write-EventLog`. See if that does what you need.